# Elastick Beanstalk - fails to run npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I I have a NodeJS environment running a very simple, and low-resource intensive app, that out of nowhere started giving me "failure to run npm install" problems.

It all started when I made a deploy, and the deployed bundle was exactly the same as the last previous successful deploy - identical in every way. But somehow, it failed to build the app. I tried rolling back, didn't work.

If I do a "environment rebuild" it magically works, then if I do ANYTHING to the environment, like changing the smallest config setting or doing a deploy (again, of a bundle exactly the same as the one running) it gives me this error.

And the worse part is: it gives me no detail at all about the problem. It just hangs forever in the command execution and then gives me the error message below. I even tried running the command manually, and the results are the same. I have no idea what is going on, and this is a PRODUCTION environment.

```
[2017-10-31T10:52:04.566Z] INFO  [20105] - [Application update 1.3.0.797-sched@71/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-10-31T10:57:21.426Z] INFO  [20105] - [Application update 1.3.0.797-sched@71/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
  npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
  Running npm install:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/bin/npm
  Setting npm config jobs to 1
  npm config jobs set to 1
  Running npm with --production flag
  Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
  UTC 2017/10/31 10:57:20 cannot find application npm debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be problems related to nano server not powerful enough to handle npm install.

ref : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=725728

You could deploy a prepackaged version of you app or increase the instance sizing.

There is also a workaround in the thread above allocating swap.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a problem related to "power". But I'm not using a nano instance, it is a t1.micro. And I'm also having problems with another app which uses a t2.micro and is regularly rising to 100% CPU in "npm build".